# Help improving question quality

Tags: discussion, questions, ban

I was recently blocked from asking questions on SO, and (sort of) know why. Could some of you look at my questions and tell me what I need to do to improve the quality of my questions? Any and all feedback (including criticism) is appreciated.

Comment: I assume you did read [my earlier comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149760/sensitivity-of-auto-question-block#comment430728_149763)?

Comment: I already have looked through, and made some edits. I know I'm not the best writer, and am looking to see how the community reacts to the edits I have made.

Comment: Okay, good. My point was not so much related to your writing though, but to the effort (or apparent absence of it) that you put into researching your problems yourself.

Comment: Note to the closers: this is not a duplicate of the aforementioned question. I am not asking to know how it works, but what I would need to do in order to provide better quality questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Users get blocked from asking questions because some of their questions get downvoted, closed and/or deleted.

All of the official reasons that a question gets closed are really just objective proxies for one singular principle: *is your question likely to be of interest to other software developers?*

Also, is your question easily answered by other, readily available resources?  We don't like duplicating information that is already available elsewhere, even on Stack Overflow itself.

> [Compiler error: "class, interface, or enum expected"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12749994/102937) -- This question is only of
>   interest to you, since it is a compiler error specific to your code.
>   Studying it is unlikely to help anyone else, since the problem is
>   already evident in the error message itself.
>
> [Setting up a wifi using
>   droid](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11067021/102937) -- is a "plz send
>   teh codez" question.  There are better resources for that, like
>   Google.
>
> [Ignoring the space delimiter in
>   Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10676813/102937) -- Appears to be a
>   question that is readily answered by the Java documentation.

Writing good questions is hard, but we ask people to make the effort anyway.  Have a look [here](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx) for tips on asking better questions.