# Improving question quality

Tags: discussion, questions

I have been trying to increase the quality of my questions on SO. and have made some edits before, but no more views came of it. Could some of you look on [My Profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1406409/azulflame?tab=questions) and tell me some things that I can do to improve those questions?

Comment: If this question is any indication, your questions are too non-specific.

Comment: what questions do you feel that you've had problems with?

Comment: hmm 7 of your 10  of your questions have accepted answers. Of the remaining 3, 1 is closed as dupe which leaves just the two questions. Perhaps if you're really looking for answers try putting a bounty on them

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Help improving question quality](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149889/help-improving-question-quality)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to think a little bit more about what the answerer will think.

here's an example

With this question: [Compiler error: “class, interface, or enum expected”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12749994/compiler-error-class-interface-or-enum-expected)

there are 2 major things wrong with this question as is.

first is the presentation

> I have been troubleshooting this program for hours, trying several configurations, and have had no luck. It has been written in java, and has 33 errors (lowered from 50 before)

your question is about a specific error, but the initial description of your problem makes the **program** the subject, and not the **error**.  My first impression was that you were asking us to read through your error log and debug your program for you, which was not actually the case, but your presentation leaves that initial impression.

second problem is that the actual code that's causing the problem isn't there for you.  we con only glean so much from the error message.

looking at the edit history I see edits with pastebin links among other things.  not everybody want's to go to an external link to get the code, and even with that, i'm surprised that  you still have the

```
/*This program is named derivativeQuiz.java, stored on a network drive I have permission to 

edit
The actual code starts below this line (with the first import statement) */
import java.util.Random;
import java.Math.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public static void derivativeQuiz(String args[])
{
    // a bunch of code
}
```

in your code.

For the record `// a bunch of code` doesn't tell us very much about what we need to know.

to conclude:  Think about the answerer when you write your questions.  Know what your problem is, and then make your questions simple, concise, and complete, and then when in doubt, read them yourself when you're done.

Ask yourself the question:  "would a stranger have the necessary details to answer my question?"  and "am i presenting those details effectively?"